# Prove that if f g and 2 are bounded, then f is also bounded

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$. 
Prove that if $f-g$ and $2fg$ are bounded, then $f$ is also bounded.

So from what I understand is that  $|f| \le M$ and $|g| \le N$. I know I can get rid of the absolute values by squaring both sides, but then what would I do from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f-g$ is bounded then $(f-g)^2=f^2+g^2-2fg$ is also bounded. You know that if $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions then $f+g$ is also bounded. So we get $f^2+g^2=(f-g)^2+2fg$ is bounded, and $f^2\le f^2+g^2$ so we get desired result.

Comment: Thank you! but what is it bounded by? I have no put it in terms of M & N.

Comment: @Mac I think it is not important. However if you want to find the upper bound of $f^2$, assume that $|f-g|\le M$ and $|fg|\le N$ then you can find to the upper bound. (Use the triangle inequality.)

Comment: Ok so... |x+y| ≤ |x| + |y|, then |f-g+2fg| ≤ |f-g| + |2fg| ≤ M+N? I dont exactly understand how I can get the bound using the inequality. This is where I was stumped.

Comment: If $|f-g|\le M$ and $|fg|\le N$ then $$|f^2+g^2|=|(f-g)^2+2fg|\le|f-g|^2+2|fg|\le M^2+2N$$. Since $|f^2|\le|f^2+g^2|$ so we get $|f^2|\le M^2+2N$.

Comment: Edit: never mind ...got it thanks!